# What version of Gradle should I use for my Flutter program?

Tags: flutter, gradle

I'm developing an app with Flutter, and it shows errors message `Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'`. Now I'm using Gradle version 8.0. But in my gradle-wrapper.properties it shows a version of 7.5.

So which version of Gradle should I use?

Comment: did you check the version is your dependencies as well ? (android/build.gradle)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.